# Bounding box algebra in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, extents

Are there efficient ways of finding the union, intersection, and difference between two bounding boxes (box2df)?

I know that this can probably be done by first converting the bounding box (`BOX2DF`) to `geometry` type and then use `ST_Union`, `ST_Intersection` etc. But before doing this on a massive scale, I just want to check if that's naive and have any performance impacts with the conversion between bounding boxes and geometries.

Are there any more efficient alternatives like [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) is to `ST_Intersects` (over envelopes)?